# RISCV 32-bit architecture on gem5 simulator

Tags: riscv, gem5

I want to study RISC-V processor in gem5 with 32-bit architecture. I have made a C executable with cross compiler riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc and I tried to test in syscall emulation mode. I don’t have any errors but the output is wrong. Have you got any ideas about it?[C program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4bS.png)
[gem5 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAqC6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the gem5 to pick the 32-bit RISC-V (by default RV64).

source: gem5/src/arc/riscv/RiscvISA.py
change the RV64 to RV32:
riscv_type = Param.RiscvType("RV64", "RV32 or RV64")
to
riscv_type = Param.RiscvType("RV32", "RV32 or RV64")

Karthy

Answer (score -1):

gem5 supports 64-bit RISC-V ISA (RV64GC to be specific) and I think, that's why you might be seeing wrong output for 32 bit binaries. I will suggest compiling your code for riscv64.

-Ayaz