# Memory failure when running gem5 SE RISCV code

Tags: c, riscv, gem5

When I try to run a simulation in SE mode in gem5 I get the following output:

`warn: No dot file generated. Please install pydot to generate the dot file and pdf. build/RISCV/mem/mem_interface.cc:791: warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes) 0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000 build/RISCV/sim/simulate.cc:194: info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation... build/RISCV/sim/mem_state.cc:443: info: Increasing stack size by one page. build/RISCV/sim/mem_state.cc:99: panic: Someone allocated physical memory at VA 0x4000000000000000 without creating a VMA! Memory Usage: 619616 KBytes Program aborted at tick 2222000`

I'm using the ELF-linux cross compiler. Compiling with the Newlib-ELF cross compiler simulates just fine, but the thing is that I need to use pthreads(openmp) and the Newlib compilation doesn't support it. To get a grip on things I tried to simulate in x86, and found out that it wont work either with a simple gnu/gcc compilation. Then I complied replicating what the test-progs folder did with *docker* and then it worked fine. Is this the way to go? Since the error says there are problems with physical memory, would compiling with docker help out, or am I missing an obviuos fix? How would go about compiling RISCV with docker (I couldn't find examples of docker+RISCV)?

Comment: Maybe this is not your problem but I just want to ask: did you compile your code for 32 bit riscv or 64 bit riscv? It seems gem5 has problems with 32 bit riscv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181691/riscv-32-bit-architecture-on-gem5-simulator So, that's why I suggest you to compile your code for RV64GC ISA with `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` as simple as`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc hello.c -o hello` But for this you firstly need to build https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain as 64 bit or just download prebuilt riscv toolchains and use 64 bit executable from there.

Comment: It doesn't differ for Docker. For example, if you are running ubuntu os on docker, you can open command line on ubuntu image in docker, git clone, build and use riscv compiler executable to compile your codes. You don't need to any DockerFile for any operation actually, just start your container or image and use as ubuntu (or other os) terminal.